# Python: How to replace the first instance of unwanted characters in a string using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I have survey data that has the answers displayed like so in a pandas dataframe:

```
A            B           C           D           E
a. cattle    c. bird     b. cat      a. cattle   1.20-60
c. bird      b. cat      a. cattle   b. cat      3.61-103
b. cat       a. cattle   c. bird     c. bird     2.10-19
```

I am trying to remove the answer reference characters/numbers ('a. ',b. ','c. ','1.,'2.',3.') and the white-space that occurs before the actual answer to leave something that looks like this:

```
A         B        C        D        E
cattle    bird     cat      cattle   20-60
bird      cat      cattle   cat      61-103
cat       cattle   bird     bird     10-19
```

the code below uses is a dictionary to state which answer reference needs to be replaced by a '':

```
df[repval_cols].replace({
 'a. ':'',
 'b. ':'',
 'c. ':'',
 '1.':'',
 '2.':'',
 '3.':'',
  }, regex=True)
```

the [repval_cols] is a list of columns in the dataframe I want this to happen to.

However the issue I am having is that the code I am using from above removes every instance of the character within the string in the columns so it leaves me with nonsensical data like this:

```
A        B       C       D       E
cttle    ird     ct      cttle   0-60
ird      ct      cttle   ct      6-0
ct       cttle   ird     ird     0-9
```

Could someone please explain why it is replacing characters that don't match what is in my dictionary? I am explicitly saying to replace 'a. ' with '' not just any 'a' within the string.

Any advice/suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string in two based on the fist period.  Then take the second item from the split pair and strip whitespace.

```
>>> (df.apply(lambda s: s.str.split('.', n=1))
       .apply(lambda s: [pair[1].strip() for pair in s])
     )
         A        B        C        D       E
0   cattle     bird      cat   cattle   20-60
1     bird      cat   cattle      cat  90-300
2      cat   cattle     bird     bird   10-19
```

For your regex statement, you need to escape the period (dot, or `.`) which is a metacharacter in regex used to match any character. To match a literal dot, you need to escape it (`\.`).

```
>>> df.replace({
 'a\. ': '',
 'b\. ': '',
 'c\. ': '',
 '1\.': '',
 '2\.': '',
 '3\.': ''}, regex=True)
        A       B       C       D       E
0  cattle    bird     cat  cattle   20-60
1    bird     cat  cattle     cat  90-300
2     cat  cattle    bird    bird   10-19
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexanderfor explaining the . as a metacharacter in regex. That fixed the issue I was having in my regex statement.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need regex for this transformation.

split the string by `.`, take the 2nd element and `strip`

```
def parse(mystr): 
    return mystr.split('.')[1].strip()

df[repval_cols].applymap(parse)
```

Here's the documentation for the [`applymap method`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap). It applies the provided function to each element in the data frame, and is analogous to the apply method.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I tried to apply this to my dataframe and I keep getting this error: 
IndexError: ('list index out of range', u'occurred at index HMBLD'). The answer above helped me solve the issue I was having with the regex statement

Answer (score 0):

> I am explicitly saying to replace 'a. ' with '' not just any 'a' within the string.

Your problem is `.` dot which is a `wildcard` in regex for **any character**.
Using `\.` which will escape it and make it *literal dot* might solve your problem.

Thus, your code becomes.

```
df[repval_cols].replace({
 'a\. ':'',
 'b\. ':'',
 'c\. ':'',
 '1\.':'',
 '2\.':'',
 '3\.':'',
  }, regex=True)
```

Comment: thanks for the info on the `.` being a `wildcard` and your answer also fixed the issue

Comment: @da4l: Am glad it did.